# Inequation of the product of ascending and random integers

Tags: number-theory, inequality

We have three sequences of positive integers $l$, $p$ and $q$ such that:
$$
p_1 \geq p_2 \geq \cdots \geq p_k\ \ and\ q_1 \geq q_2 \geq \cdots \geq q_k \geq \cdots \geq q_h \ \ where:\ \ k < h 
$$

and

$$
0\leq l_1 \leq l_2 \cdots \leq l_k\leq \cdots \leq l_h
$$

and
$$
p_1+2p_2+\cdots+kp_k < q_1+2q_2+\cdots+kq_k+\cdots+hq_h
$$

and

$$
p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_k = q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_k+\cdots+q_h=n
$$

Is the following statement true:

$$
l_1(p_1-q_1)+l_2(p_2-q_2)+\cdots+l_k(p_k-q_k) \leq l_k(p_1-q_1)+l_k(p_2-q_2)+\cdots+l_k(p_k-q_k)
$$

This proof will help me to prove another result that uses it in its proof.

Best regards

Comment: You can only prove a statement if it is true. So it would be better to ask if the statement in your post is true.

Comment: @GHfromMO I edited as you suggested

Comment: I am not happy with your edit as you still say "I need to prove". Once again, you can only prove something that is true. For example, it would be meaningless to say "I need to prove that 0=1", simply because "0=1" is false.

Comment: @GHfromMO Sorry, i did not get pay attention to the first line, I edited again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample is given by $k=2$, $h=3$, $n=18$,
$$p_1=9, p_2=9, q_1=10, q_2=4, q_3=4, l_1=1, 
l_2=2, l_3=2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, in this case, how can we get a close upper bound to $l_1(p_1-q_1)+\cdots+l_k(p_k-q_k)$ using the information given in the question ?

Comment: @BADJARAMohamedelAmine : Such additional 
questions should be asked separately, perhaps posted elsewhere. Anyhow,  given lots of degrees of freedom allowed for the $l_i$'s, and in view of the [Farkas lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma#Geometric_interpretation), I think in general there is no finite upper bound at all on $l_1(p_1-q_1)+l_2(p_2-q_2)+\cdots+l_k(p_k-q_k)$.